# Stop IE from caching iframe opened via jquery modal dialog

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, iframe, cache-control

**UPDATED**: Found answer.  Cannot submit my own answer for 7 more hours...  See comments.

I'm opening a dialog as follows:

```
url = 'edit/MyPage.aspx?appid=3&value=4&' + date.getTime();
$('#modalIFrame').attr('src', url);
$('#modalDiv').dialog('open');
```

The iframe has a form with a few fields (checkboxes, dropdowns, textareas).  In Chrome, everything is working flawelessly.  In IE it caches *very* persistently and annoyingly.  Even shift+refresh doesn't help.  So if I open the dialog, make changes, hit submit, then refresh the page all the data looks right.  However, when I click the edit button to open the dialog, it's the previous data (The data is pulled using an ajax call to a WCF service)  I've even waited a couple hours for my session to expire, no luck.

As you can see above, I tried a trick I found here to trick IE into thinking it's a new page.  This doesn't work.  I also added the following code to the Page_Load of the page in the iframe:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
```

and the following meta tags to the HTML:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="0">
```

I'm completely lost here, any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Okay, so I can't answer my own question, but...

Comment: Okay I discovered it was the WCF service that was being cached in IE.  Seems weird to me, but I added a timestamp to the ajax call and now it works!

    var date = new Date();
    data: { "appid": appid, "serverid": serverid, "timestamp": date.getTime() },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I discovered it was the WCF service that was being cached in IE (doesn't make sense to me, but whatever).  I added a timestamp to the ajax call and now it works!

```
data: { "appid": appid, "serverid": serverid, "timestamp": date.getTime() },
```

Comment: I would like to know why we have to "hack" this way... I too was getting this issue - and by adding a time stamp, i can see that it forces it to go since it is not the same call, but why is it cached and is there a correct way to tell it not to?

Comment: Wish I could help, but I've moved on and this never got much attention.